# Eclipse CDT Showing False Error Icons

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, code-analysis

Eclipse CDT frequently shows many error icons in front of file names which suggest the code analyser discovered some errors. However, upon opening the file, the error icon disappear! This seems to happen after I run the Code Analyser and/or the Indexer, and it seems to happen on all files. This is really annoying because it makes the icons useless as I cannot tell from the icons whether the files have errors or not; I have to open all files one by one to know which files have problems. Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: I also have this problem. This should be reported as a bug to eclipse project site.

Answer (score 0):

Try rebuilding index, and then close and open project to force icon refresh.

If this doesn't fix the issue. You shall check if the include paths are valid.